# Android ndk atof()

Tags: android, android-ndk, atof

Hi i have an android project which uses ndk

there is a c function atof() which is defined

```
static __inline__ double atof(const char *nptr)
{
    return (strtod(nptr, NULL));
}
```

But somehow it always results in 0.0

```
error_printf("found %s parsed %d \n",nextArg, atof(nextArg));
found 44 parsed 0
```

any ideas why?

the parameter nextArg seems not to be the Problem

```
error_printf("found %s parsed %d \n","123", atof("123"));
found 123 parsed 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your print message from `%d`, which expects a 32-bit integer, to `%f`, which expects a 64-bit floating-point value.

Your print statement is showing the low 32 bits of its argument, which happen to be all zeroes because of your chosen test input.  If you printed `atof(123.3)` you'd see a nonzero value from `%d`.

And, of course, make sure you have `#include <stdlib.h>` to ensure you have the prototypes for `atof()` and `strtod()`.